# Profiling code not working for Odoo version 15.0

Tags: odoo-15

I am adding profiler on my custom method on Odoo v15.0
I have referred below doc for code profiling
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/profilecode.html

Below is the syntax i am using

```
from odoo.tools.profiler import profile
@profile
@api.model
def mymethod(...):
  My code
```

But on execution of code i am getting below error on terminal
"ImportError: cannot import name 'profile' from 'odoo.tools.profiler'"

To debug the issue i have deep dived in base code of "/odoo/tool/profiler.py".
But unable to locate any wrapper or function called profiler.

What is correct way to use profiling using "Log a method" strategy on  odoo v15.0?

Answer (score 0):

Goto [path](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/15.0/odoo/tools) and make sure you have this file for line-by-line code profiling looks like you don't have this file

From the front end in debug mode open enable profiling, this will give you all the information per user

[image: Odoo 15 Profiling]

Comment: I have the profiler.py file in odoo/tool directory but i still get error "ImportError: cannot import name 'profile' from 'odoo.tools.profiler'"

Comment: okay, then check your addons paths if they are configured correctly, try to import another file from tools. If nothing works, check permission,
try to add tools specifically in the addons path that will give a better error if there is still no error then I give up